# Cables with different cross section having the same max allowed current?

Tags: cables, current-rating

I was looking to buy a power cable recently and my eye caught this weird fact.

Look at these two cables:

- https://www.savio.net.pl/en/product/savio-1-8-m-schuko-m-power-cable-iec-c13-cl-138/
- https://www.savio.net.pl/en/product/savio-cl-89-1-2-m-schuko-male-power-cable-iec-c13/

They both claim to have max values of:

```
Cable parameters: 250 V max, 10 A max
```

Yet, one of them claims to have a cross section of 0.75 mm<sup>2</sup>, while the other one 0.5 mm<sup>2</sup>.

How is this possible? Shouldn't there be a difference in the max current as well?

I guess the metal for the cable should be the same (copper), right?

Note: In case you happen to see at the product card (the PDF link), according to the manufacturer, the information for the cl-89 is wrong and the one in the web page is correct (there were conflicting values reported and I had to ask them - hopefully they are not mistaken as well).

**Update:**

Shortly after my communication with the manufacturer about the conflicting information about the CL-89 model on their site, they have updated the cable rating as well. It now says 2A max! So, I guess the problem was the completely wrong labeling on that model after all... Let's hope no-one's home caught fire from this...

Comment: That's almost ***exactly*** the difference between using copper and aluminum. Given a cross sectional area of \$0.5\:\text{mm}^2\$, copper resistance is \$34.5\:\frac{\Omega}{\text{km}}\$. Given a cross sectional area of \$0.75\:\text{mm}^2\$, aluminum resistance is \$35.3\:\frac{\Omega}{\text{km}}\$. It's probably a different in metal, other things being equal.

Comment: @jonk That sounds like an answer to me. I imagine easy to test, as well--buy one of each cable and sacrifice them on the altar to science, cutting them both in half to see if the conductors are copper-colored or aluminum-colored.

Comment: There are other factors that effect the current capacity other then the conductor material. Some are insulation rating, length of the conductor and allowed temperature rise.

Comment: 10A Cordsets are also  limited in Amps by 70’C connector surface temp, whereas UL accepts 13A at a higher temp.

Comment: @jonk Aluminium cables are not allowed in the du for general appliances. They are both copper.

Comment: @jonk - That's an ingenious explanation, but almost certainly wrong. For the sort of cord being discussed, flexibility requires stranded wire, not solid, and they just don't make stranded aluminum wire.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It was the first thing that crossed my mind, for obvious reasons. So I just went and looked up the conductance table values. (I decided not to worry about the fact that copper isn't copper, as it is almost always amalgamated and one supplier's copper is different than another's.) What took me by surprise is how conveniently the numbers worked out. I had no idea what I'd find, when I thought to check. But upon finding that coincidence, I decided to toss out the idea onto the table top for others to examine. I guess you have done so, now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IEC plugs are rated 10A maximum, so the wire may have nothing to do with it, if they simply looked at the plug and printed that onto the marketing material. The Schuko plug is allowed to be used for 16A and 10A loads in general, but the actual plug on that cable may not be 16A rated.

However, 10A through 0.5mm² wire, I don't know if that is according to European electrical codes, it does sound awfully lot for that wire thickness.

One chart found googling had rated 3A for 0.5mm² mains cable, and 16A for 1.5mm² mains cabling - the latter matches 16A rated extension cords.

Comment: Yes, I had the some doubts about the 10A and that cross section too. And I wanted to compare it against another cable, but I didn't know what to use as a reference. If the metal used can be different as well, things get even more complicated when it comes to comparisons...

Answer (score 5):

10A through 0.5mm cable? I don't believe it.

Looking closer, it seems that the second one has a typo on the website

click the product card link for the straight dope.

> Model: CL-89

> Cable parameters: 250 V max, 10 A max
>
> Specification: **3 * 0.75 mm2**, OD: 6.8 mm

If you seaarch on the EAN "5901986041467" You'll find other vendors publishing the correct discription.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I had to ask the manufacturer about this and they've said that the correct value was 0.5 mm2, not the one on the product card. I am not sure if they are mistaken as well. They might be mistaken, because the original automated email response that I got was saying that they are on vacations and that I should forward my email to another email address within their company. Perhaps their experts are away.

Comment: it seems surprising that all the other vendors would have the wrong number.

Answer (score 3):

They are electrically equivalent, so will produce the same voltage drop across cable.  Shorter cable so why use a larger conductor.  Cheaper manufacturing and more profit.

The trick is Area is given in \$mm^2\$.

Using \$1.72 \times 10^{-8} Ω \cdot m\$ as resistivity of copper @20°C.

$$R = \frac {\rho \ ℓ}{A} = \frac {1.72 \times 10^{-8} Ω \cdot m \times 1.8m \times 2} {0.75 mm^2} = \frac {1.72 \times 10^{-8} Ω \cdot m \times 1.8m \times 2} {0.75 \times 10^{-6} m^2} = 82.56 mΩ$$

$$R = \frac {\rho \ ℓ}{A} = \frac {1.72 \times 10^{-8} Ω \cdot m \times 1.2m \times 2} {0.5 mm^2} = 82.56 mΩ$$

Comment: The overall electrical resistance would be the same for the two cables, but the temperature rise would not. The shorter the cable is, the less material there is to absorb the heat and the less surface area to dissipate it. That's why electrical wiring rating usually only consider the cross-section of the cable.

Comment: @Zakinster  Yes. Shorter cable can take advantage of smaller conductor saving 1/3 the copper but must be warmer.

Answer (score 2):

First, the thickness of the cable is irrelevant, since it includes insulation.

Second, there *is* a difference in conductor size,  3 * 0.5 mm2 vs. 3 * 0.75 mm2, 50% more area. However, the cables are also different lengths, with the longer cable having larger conductors. That *might* mean that voltage drop, rather than *heating*, is the limiting factor.

Comment: Doesn't the cross section exclude the insulator? Why would they include it in the measurement? And, I haven't done any calculations, but I would expect that for ~2m of cable there wouldn't be such a noticeable drop of voltage. But I will try to do the calculations to be sure.

Comment: 3 * 0.5 mm² and 3 * 0.75 mm² are common wire sizes, and these only include the copper, not the insulation, so the first part of the answer is plain wrong.

Comment: @Justme I think the term "cable" refers to both the wire and insulation.

Comment: @dandavis that's how the mains cords are marked, I did not invent the notation.

Comment: Downvote: I would not put 10A through 0,5 mm2 as it will get too hot.

Answer (score 1):

These are not bare cables, they are cable assemblies. The current rating might be determined by the connectors or for some regulatory reason.

Comment: Same connector: IEC C13 – C / F Schuko.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is printed on the device is a usage rating, which cannot exceed the maximum rating dictated by the engineering constraints, but may well be lower.

It's perfectly possible that the thicker cable can actually carry more than 10A, but is rated for 10A because adhering to standard ratings is a better marketing strategy, or because the manufacturer decided to go for a higher safety margin in this product line.